# Join only selected items from the list

Tags: python

How to join so that I get the result: e.g: 000C

How to join only selected items from the list? in this case list[1] and list[2]

```
list = [0A,00,0C,20,10,AC]
print ("".join(map(str, list)))
>>> 123456
```

Comment: your list value is wrong, you can't set values like this, this not string and not number7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list with your selection indices and use it to join what you want:

```
list = ["0A","00","0C","20","10","AC"]
sel = [1,2]
print ("".join(map(str, [list[i] for i in sel])))
```